# Groovy: Different behaviour observed using the eachWithIndex method

Tags: groovy

I was doing a Groovy tutorial online there and after playing around with the code I observed some behaviour that I can't understand.

First I created a Map object like this:

```
def devMap = [:]
devMap = ['name':'Frankie', 'framework':'Grails', 'language':'Groovy']
devMap.put('lastName','Hollywood')
```

Then I called `eachWithIndex` to print out the values like so:

```
devMap.eachWithIndex { println "$it.key: $it.value"}
```

Which printed this to the console:

```
name: Frankie
framework: Grails
language: Groovy
lastName: Hollywood
```

But when I printed to the console from the `eachWithIndex` method like this using the arrow operator:

```
devMap.eachWithIndex { it, i -> println "$i: $it" }
```

The following got printed to the console:

```
0: name=Frankie
1: framework=Grails
2: language=Groovy
3: lastName=Hollywood
```

So what I can't understand is why the indexes got printed with the second statement and why there are `=` signs but no `:` signs between the key-value pairs?

Thanks.

Comment: The indexes are printed because you're telling the code to print it:  "$i" is the index.

Comment: I thought that was the reason. Any idea about the equals signs?

Comment: it is the toString() of Map.Entry class that prints with the equals.

Comment: I see, makes sense thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the no-arg version of `eachWithIndex`, `it` is the current entry in the Map. That means that `it.key` and `it.value` return what you expect.

When you use the two-arg version of `eachWithIndex`, again, `it` is the current entry in the Map and `i` is the current index. You're printing `i`, the index, and then since you are only printing `it`, you are getting the result of `it.toString()`, which formats the map entry as `"${it.key}=${it.value}"`

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is equivalent to:

```
devMap.eachWithIndex { it, index -> println "$index: ${it.toString()}" }
```

where this shows that the `toString()` implementation uses the `=` syntax:

```
devMap.each { println it.toString() }
```

Note that this is closer to your goal (as I interpret it):

```
devMap.eachWithIndex { it, index -> println "$index: ${it.key}: ${it.value}" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!